# Intersection of relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

The below relations are given AUFTRAG($A_1, A_2, A_3$) and KUNDE($B_1, B_2, B_3$) with $A_1$ = AUFTRNR, $A_2$ = DATUM, $A_3$ = KUNDNR, $B_1$ = KUNDNR, $B_2$ = NAME and $B_3$ = ORT.

[image]

I want to calculate AUFTRAG $\cap$ KUNDE.

It holds that $R\cap S=R\setminus (R\setminus S)$.

First we consider $R\setminus S$, so at the table AUFTRAG we delete the elements that are also in KUNDE.

The column KUNDNR is common so we delete the rows that are in common.

[image]

We delete this row from AUFTRAG and get :

[image]

Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean with "intersection" ($\cap$) ? In set theory relations a sets and the intersection of two sets is the set of common elements. If the two tables above define relation AUFTRAG and relation KUNDE, there is no common element.

Comment: Maybe some sort of [Join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))?